# How to local storage expand/collapse CSS settings

Tags: javascript, css, html, local-storage, web-storage

I'm looking for way to use local storage to remember the CSS settings of a expand/collapse element

so for my JavaScript looks like this (which grabs the id and handles the expand/collapse)

```
function toggleHeight(id, link) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if(e.style.maxHeight == '450px') {
        e.style.maxHeight = '0px'; 
    } else {
        e.style.maxHeight = '450px';
    }
}
```

So what I am looking for is something that grabs the div id på clicking a link and stores the changes when clicking and then remembering is when refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised here is my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleHeight(id, link) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
var height = localStorage.getItem(id);

if(e.style.maxHeight == '450px' || e.style.maxHeight == 'inherit') {
    e.style.maxHeight = '0px'; 
    localStorage.setItem(id,"closed");
} else {
    e.style.maxHeight = '450px';
    localStorage.setItem(id, "open");
}
}

  function load() { 

var setting
var e
var link
for (x in localStorage){
    setting = localStorage.getItem(x);
    e = document.getElementById(x);
    link = document.getElementById('forumlink'+x);

    if (setting == 'open')
    {
        e.style.maxHeight = '450px';
    }
    else
    {
        e.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }   
    }
    }

</script>
```

This stores the state of the div when clicked and sets in to open/closed

On page load it grabs the stored value and sets the max-height css after the open/closed value..

Hope some others can make use of this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
var height = localStorage.getItem(id+"-height");

localStorage.setItem(id+"-height", height);
```

Comment: yes i am getting somewhere with this, but not it is not grabing the height css setting of the div and it stores it as value NULL

Comment: replacing the set item value "height" with "e.style.maxHeight" like this: stores the height so thx alot :)

var height = localStorage.getItem(id+"-height");
localStorage.setItem(id+"-height", e.style.maxHeight);

Comment: Well yes, you need to set the height before writing it to the storage :) - Feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I got it to work with storing the height and then calling on load, and with help from a loop i made it as simple as possible and it works swimmingly :)

I will post my solution as soon as i can (i have less than 10 reputation so i have to wait)

Comment: Well, just by accepting an answer you get more rep, so you're getting there :)

Comment: storing the actual height is pretty nasty... What if for some reason the layout changes to a maxHeight of 500px? You saved 400px on the client-side so the client got a screwed up layout.. an even better approach to show/hide is using `e.style.display= '';` <-> `e.style.display= 'none';`

Comment: I am storing as open/closed but you have a point. Right now I am doing this with css3 transition effect which makes it easier with max-height setting. but and I am working on making it with display 1/none instead with jQuery instead

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it: working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/XZf72/)

```
//extra methods to get and set objects in staid of strings
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
//fetch the object or make a new and set constant values    
var toggleState = localStorage.getObject('toggleState') || {},
    MIN_SIZE= '0px',
    MAX_SIZE= '450px';

//shown is an optional parameter
function toggleHeight(id, shown) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(shown === true || (typeof shown === "undefined" && e.style.maxHeight == MIN_SIZE)) {
       show(id);
    } else {
       hide(id);
    }
}

function show(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.maxHeight = MAX_SIZE;
    toggleState[id] = true;
    localStorage.setObject('toggleState',toggleState);
}
function hide(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.maxHeight = MIN_SIZE;
    toggleState[id] = false;
    localStorage.setObject('toggleState',toggleState);
}
//loop over it to set initial values
for(var i in toggleState){
    toggleHeight(i, toggleState[i]);
}

//do manual toggle, hide, show

toggleHeight('someID');​
```

You see I separated the show and hide so you can show hide them individually too, if you want or you can still use the toggle method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer got me closer, but ended up with something alot simpler